# JS assigning a function to an object is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have recently updated a Vue2 project to a Vue3 project and it seems like there is a bug in the Javascript language now. Javascript will not let me assign a function to an object.

Below I create a function "bar" in the loop. I can call the function in the loop "bar(i)", I can call the function out of the loop "ff('00')" but cannot assign the function to the api_calls object!!!! I have no idea why.

Can someone please point at what I am doing wrong?

I also upgrade from node-v10.15.3-x64 to node-v18.16.0-x64.

```
export function generate_api_calls(app_name) {
  let api_calls = {}

  api_calls['cameraFeed'] = `http://${hostname}:${camera_port}${CAMERA_FEED_URL}`

  let ff
  let items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  for (let i in items) {
    let name = items[i]
    function bar(j) {
      logger.info(`bar ${j}`)
    };

    bar(i)
    ff = bar
    api_calls[name] = bar;
    logger.info(`generate_api_calls api ${name} ${JSON.stringify(api_calls)}`)
    logger.info(`generate_api_calls api ${JSON.stringify(api_calls[name])}`)
  }
  ff('00');
 
  logger.info(`generate_api_calls 5 ${JSON.stringify(api_calls)}`)
  return api_calls
}
```

This produces

```
2023-05-30_17:39:24.582-gui.vue.app-INFO: bar 0
2023-05-30_17:39:24.582-gui.vue.app-INFO: generate_api_calls api 1 {"cameraFeed":"http://localhost:5051/camera/feed"}
2023-05-30_17:39:24.583-gui.vue.app-INFO: generate_api_calls api undefined
2023-05-30_17:39:24.583-gui.vue.app-INFO: bar 1
2023-05-30_17:39:24.584-gui.vue.app-INFO: generate_api_calls api 2 {"cameraFeed":"http://localhost:5051/camera/feed"}
2023-05-30_17:39:24.584-gui.vue.app-INFO: generate_api_calls api undefined
2023-05-30_17:39:24.585-gui.vue.app-INFO: bar 2
2023-05-30_17:39:24.585-gui.vue.app-INFO: generate_api_calls api 3 {"cameraFeed":"http://localhost:5051/camera/feed"}
2023-05-30_17:39:24.586-gui.vue.app-INFO: generate_api_calls api undefined
2023-05-30_17:39:24.586-gui.vue.app-INFO: bar 3
2023-05-30_17:39:24.587-gui.vue.app-INFO: generate_api_calls api 4 {"cameraFeed":"http://localhost:5051/camera/feed"}
2023-05-30_17:39:24.587-gui.vue.app-INFO: generate_api_calls api undefined
2023-05-30_17:39:24.588-gui.vue.app-INFO: bar 00
2023-05-30_17:39:24.588-gui.vue.app-INFO: generate_api_calls 5 {"cameraFeed":"http://localhost:5051/camera/feed"}
```

Comment: The function is there. It's just that `JSON.stringify()` [doesn't work on function values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description). `JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify)` will also return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works as intended. You just cannot `JSON.stringify` functions.
Please see the demo below.

```js
const logger = {
  info: console.log,
};

function generate_api_calls(app_name) {
  let api_calls = {};

  api_calls['cameraFeed'] = 'cameraFeed';

  let ff;
  let items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  for (let i in items) {
    let name = items[i];

    function bar(j) {
      logger.info(`bar ${j}`);
    };

    bar(i);
    ff = bar;
    api_calls[name] = bar;
    console.log('watch me printing function --->', api_calls[name]);
    logger.info(`generate_api_calls api ${name} ${JSON.stringify(api_calls)}`)
    logger.info(`generate_api_calls api ${JSON.stringify(api_calls[name])}`)
  }
  ff('00');

  console.log('watch me printing api_calls --->', api_calls);

  logger.info(`generate_api_calls 5 ${JSON.stringify(api_calls)}`)
  return api_calls
}

generate_api_calls('test');

// see how stringify skips function
console.log(JSON.stringify({
  data: 'abc',
  func: () => {},
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! I could have sworn that JSON.stringify just prints "[object.Object]" for objects. My bad!